# try to lock in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, synchronization, locking

in pthread library it is possible to find non blocking function:

```
int pthread_mutex_trylock(pthread_mutex_t *mutex);
```

can I find something similar  in `Windows`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a critical section for your lock then the equivalent is [`TryEnterCriticalSection()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686857%28VS.85%29.aspx).

If you are using a mutex for your lock then the equivalent is to call [`WaitForSingleObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) passing `0` as the timeout.

If you are unfamiliar with Windows synchronisation objects, don't be fooled into preferring the mutex because it has a name that you are most familiar with from a pthreads background.  So long as your synchronisation is within process, critical sections are more efficient and easier to use.

Comment: David Heffernan: can I use TryEnterCriticalSection() for different processes? not threads?

Comment: @yeap Critical sections don't work across processes. For cross-process locks you need the [mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686927(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Note that the return behaviours differ between pthread_mutex_trylock and TryEnterCriticalSection for the case where the calling thread already owns the lock. In both implementations, you own the lock later, but the return code is different. There are three preconditions (nobody owns it, we own it, someone else owns it) and two final states (we own it, or we don't) via two different possible behaviours (we locked it, or we didn't lock it). TryEnterCriticalSection returns zero if another thread owned the critical section. pthread_mutex_trylock returns non-zero if any thread owned the mutex. Ugh.

Answer (score -1):

You could check the Boost library. They have something called [shareable_locks](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost/interprocess/sharable_lock.html).
This is part of the [Boost Interprocess Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) which works in both Windows and Unix.